# Stream two collections and collect a map based on common property

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, stream

I have looked around a bit but have not found a elegant solution. What I am trying to do is have a nice streamlined (pun intended) solution to create a map from two collections who have 1 shared property (an id of sorts). The map should be key-value of the matching objects. How I have done it for now is a forEach on collection1 and within a foreEach on collection 2 to get the matching model and then do an operation on it. I would like to create the map and then separately just do the operation on every pair in the map. I have tried to come up with a simple example to make it a bit more clear.

```
data class FirstNameModel(val idNumber: String, val firstName: String)
data class LastNameModel(val idNumber: String, val lastName: String)

val randomFirstNameList = listOf(
   FirstNameModel("5631ab", "Bob"),
   FirstNameModel("ca790a", "George"),
   FirstNameModel("j8f1sa", "Alice")
)

val randomLastNameList = listOf(
   LastNameModel("j8f1sa", "Smith"),
   LastNameModel("5631ab", "Johnson"),
   LastNameModel("ca790a", "Takai")
)

// stream function to correctly create map (not just a null one like below).

val map: Map<FirstNameModel, LastNameModel>? = null

fun printIt() {
   map?.forEach {
       println("Name for id ${it.key.idNumber} is ${it.key.firstName} ${it.value.lastName}")
   }
//    should print something like:
//            Name for id 5631ab is Bob Johnson
//            Name for id ca790a is George Takai
//            Name for id j8f1sa is Alice Smith
}
```

I have been trying this in Kotlin for now but its a usecase I sometimes also have in Java, so am curios for both.

Comment: In your example, each item in each list has a corresponding element in the other list with the same id. What if there is no matching element for a particular element in the other list? Let's say there is an extra `LastNameModel("abcdef", "Jones")` and `FirstNameModel("ghijkl", "Claire")`. How will that affect the output map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work including the cases mentioned in @Sweeper's (thanks!) comment below the question:

```
val map: Map<FirstNameModel, LastNameModel> = randomFirstNameList.map { it.idNumber }
  .plus(randomLastNameList.map { it.idNumber })
  .distinct()
  .associate { idNumber ->
    (randomFirstNameList.firstOrNull { it.idNumber == idNumber } ?: FirstNameModel(idNumber, "")) to
    (randomLastNameList.firstOrNull { it.idNumber == idNumber } ?: LastNameModel(idNumber, ""))
  }
```

But it probably would make sense to introduce a data class to hold the result:

```
data class NameModel(val idNumber: String, val firstName: String, val lastName: String)

val map: List<NameModel> = randomFirstNameList.map { it.idNumber }
  .plus(randomLastNameList.map { it.idNumber })
  .distinct()
  .map { idNumber ->
    NameModel(
      idNumber,
      randomFirstNameList.firstOrNull { it.idNumber == idNumber }?.firstName ?: "",
      randomLastNameList.firstOrNull { it.idNumber == idNumber }?.lastName ?: ""
    )
  }
```

Output (including one last name entry without corresponding first name entry):

```
NameModel(idNumber=5631ab, firstName=Bob, lastName=Johnson)
NameModel(idNumber=ca790a, firstName=George, lastName=Takai)
NameModel(idNumber=j8f1sa, firstName=Alice, lastName=Smith)
NameModel(idNumber=999999, firstName=, lastName=NoFirstName)
```

Additional remark:

If the two lists are very large, the repeated *firstOrNull* calls could increase time consumption. In such a case it would make sense to create lookup maps for first and last names:

```
val firstNameMap = randomFirstNameList.associate { it.idNumber to it.firstName }
val lastNameMap = randomLastNameList.associate { it.idNumber to it.lastName }

val map: List<NameModel> = randomFirstNameList.map { it.idNumber }
  .plus(randomLastNameList.map { it.idNumber })
  .distinct()
  .map { idNumber ->
    NameModel(
      idNumber,
      firstNameMap.getOrElse(idNumber) { "" },
      lastNameMap.getOrElse(idNumber) { "" }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out with some things I was quite close but did it a bit wrong. For me the case of mismatch between id's wont be an issue because of the surrounding logic (this is something I also check for) but it is very nice to include it into the answer. I will also think about the class to hold the result...